# What is the origin of the expression "to twig to something"?

Tags: etymology

Oddly enough, the OED (1971 Compact Edition) has no entry for *twig to*, only for *twig something*:

> *twig v<sup>4</sup>* slang or colloq. **[Origin unascertained]**
>
> [...]
>
> b. To become aware of by seeing; to perceive, discern, catch sight of; to recognize.
>
> 1796 J. G. Holman *Abroad & at Home* iii. ii, ― He twigs me. He knows
> Dicky here in his real and masquerade character both.
>
> 1801 M. G. Lewis *Tales Wonder, Sailor’s T*. ii, ― With strange surprise and fear, Jack Tackle’s ghost I twigg’d.
>
> 1825 Lady Granville *Lett*. 30 Jan. (1894) I. 339 ― They have twigged me.
>
> 1860 *Hunting Grounds Old World Ser*. i. xii. (ed. 2) 189 ― The leader, whom at last I twigged lying down and chewing the cud.
>
> 1879 F. Pollok *Sport Brit. Burmah* I. 191, ― I twigged the tigress creeping away in front of us.

Still, that's clearly the same as *twig to* so it will serve. What is the origin of this expression? Neither the OED nor [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=twig&allowed_in_frame=0) provide any etymological information for this meaning of the word *twig*. It occurred to me that it might come from a hunting/tracking analogy where the sound of a broken twig would alert the hunter to the presence of their prey or the prey to the presence of the hunter. Is there anything to this or am I making it all up?

Comment: If OED say *origin unascertained*, I don't see any chance we'll be able to give you a better "authoritative" answer here. Fairly obviously the (relatively uncommon) inclusion of an extraneous ***to*** doesn't affect either the meaning or the etymology. My guess is that may be partly caused by association with, say, *to cotton [on] **to** something*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, I'm not too bothered about the _to_, which is why I included the definition quoted. However, I've actually received [at least one answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/127938/25030) here which improved on the OED and [another](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118919/25030) which quoted original research beyond what found on etymonline so I wouldn't rule it out. I am not looking for opinion here but for actual evidence one way or another. This is, after all, (also) a site for professional linguists so I hope one of them might have something to add.

Comment: If Ken Greenwald is still active on Wordwizard, you might want to ask there. His sleuthing is legendary; OED is about number 20 in his resource-checking order.

Comment: Hmm, I know it as "to twig onto something".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twig#Etymology_2) says this verb *twig* is from Irish and Scottish Gaelic *tuig* ‎(“to understand”).

Irish editor Stan Carey wrote on the [Macmillan Dictionary blog](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/can-you-twig-it) in September 2014:

> At an early age in Ireland I learned the Irish word *tuig*, meaning ‘understand’, often used in common phrases like *An dtuigeann tú*? (‘Do you understand?’). You can hear several regional pronunciations of the word at the excellent Irish dictionary website [Foclóir.ie](http://www.focloir.ie/en/dictionary/ei/understand). Comparing *tuig* with *twig* we [World Wide Words writer Michael Quinion, and Carey] find they sound alike and mean similar things. Of course, this could simply be coincidental – but the correspondence, while inconclusive, is certainly suggestive.
>
> Terence Dolan’s *Dictionary of Hiberno-English* says this Irish derivation for *twig* is possible, while Loreto Todd’s *Green English* says it ‘may well’ be the origin. Bernard Share’s *Slanguage* is less convinced, indicating instead that the two words have been confused. That’s a possibility, and it should be noted that *tuig* ‘understand’ is a word in Scottish Gaelic too. So the etymology of the verb *twig* remains uncertain, but Irish *tuig* seems to me a good candidate. If you’ve other ideas, let us know in the comments.

A comment from Colin McCarthy reads:

> Your suggested derivation receives some support from Sean Beecher (1991 *A Dictionary of Cork Slang* The Collins Press). To quote from page 103, “Twig, To, verb. To understand. Use: You twig? You understand? Derivation: Possibly Irish ‘Tuig’ – to understand. And note ‘Twig’ – a divining rod for water, hence by extension ‘understanding’. Wright. And also ‘Twig’ – I catch your meaning, I understand (Irish ‘Tuigim’ – I notice). Brewer.”

And this comment from Michael Parsley:

> *Webster’s International Dictionary* gives, in addition to the meaning of a ‘small shoot without leaves’, the meaning of to use a twig as a diving rod (searching for water).
>
> This might be a source of the meaning to understand (suddenly).

Answer (score 0):

In a phrase like 'Why don't you twig on to the fact that ....' that sounds very similar to the present tense of Irish *tuig*, which is *tuigeann* (pronounced closely to 'twig on'). In Irish,'she understands ...' would be '*tuigeann sí* ...'.

Irish *sí* is pronounced extremely closely to English *she* and has the same meaning in this context.

The Irish *tui* has more of a glide sound than a full-on w, but an English ear could easily think there was a w in there.

Comment: Could you clarify in which dialects of Irish this off-glide would be found? I don’t recall ever hearing a glide, and the standardised pronunciation given on Wiktionary, /tˠɪgʲ ~ tɪg’/, doesn’t have one either. Considering that _(an) dtuig(eann)_ is the origin of English _dig_ (as in ‘you dig?’ = ‘you understand?’), at least some English speakers didn’t hear any glide either. In general, Anglicised Irish names sometimes have a w after velars and s (Gweedore, Sweeney) but sometimes not (Kevin); but never elsewhere (Felan, Malcolm, all the places with Tieve/Teev = _taobh_).

Comment: https://www.teanglann.ie/en/fuaim/tuig - if you click on the Ulster pronunciation particularly. It's not present in Connacht and debatable in Munster.

Comment: As a speaker of Ulster (well, Donegal) Irish myself, I detect no glide at all in the word. The pronunciation provided by Teanglann here sounds more like _taig_ to me. Is it perhaps an east Ulster thing?

Comment: B'fhéidir. Cloisim féin an 'w', ach is Sasanach mise, is dócha go bhfuil mo chuid cluasa difriúil. It's possible that an English ear hears it but not an Irish speaker?

Comment: It could be (though I’m not a native speaker either – I am a sometime phonetician, though).