# Word that encompasses "passion" and "suffering"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun that has identical or similar meanings to the following:

> (a) Powerful feeling that overwhelms someone, often clouding their judgement. (b) passion (c) excessive love for something (d) moral suffering

Also, if possible, an adjective form of this noun would be useful.

An example sentence is added below (and for the adjective form):

> 1) However, the night unchains the azure’s potentiality, channelling its fury through relentless waves that permeate even the calmest psyche. The ocean’s nocturne nature makes me, inevitably, compare it to the _____ and tumultuous man’s nature which hides its decadence in a facile obscurity.

More example sentences:

> 2) He's a ____ man that lost his wealth to gambling.(for the adjective form)
>
> 3) Overindulging in drinking and whoring around is the mark of the _____. (for the noun form)
>
> 4) He is thinking about her all the time. He's ____ about her.
>
> 5) A great _____ blinded him, and thus he texted her back.

Comment: Why does "passioante" not fit? [Passion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passion), in itself, can imply suffering.

Comment: I will use passionate/passion if I can't find a word that has the aforementioned desired meanings. I am not choosing passion at the moment because it only implies suffering and doesn't have it as an explicit meaning.

Comment: Looking at Cambridge Dictionary, Oxford Dictionary, and at Merriam-Webster, I can't see anywhere a kind of suffering as one of the meanings of passion.

Comment: Excepting the suffering of Jesus Christ.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passion Definition 2. Additionally, the word passion comes from the Greek verb **πασχω**, meaning *to suffer* and Late Latin **passionem**, meaning *suffering, enduring*.

Comment: I've just said "it only implies suffering and doesn't have it as an explicit meaning." I'm looking for a noun that also explicitly means suffering, as in having it as an explicit meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your information in regards to the origin of the word from Greek, but it doesn't help me at all if I write in English. Having something implicitly is quite different from having it explicitly.

Comment: Martyrdom comes to mind, as does endurance.

Comment: "Passionate works for 1). "Addiction/addicted" works for 2) and 3). "Obsession/obsessed" works for 4) and 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term **lust** can imply suffering, if it is unreciprocated. It is certainly related to passion  and the idea of indulgence and excess.

- Overindulging in drinking and whoring around is the mark of the **lusting**/ **lustful**.
- He is thinking about her all the time. He's **lusting** for her.
- A great **lust** blinded him, and thus he texted her back.

Alternatively, the OP could use the term **rage** which the Oxford English Dictionary defines it as "a vehement passion for, desire of, a thing" (sense 7a) and was used by Shakespeare, in it oldest quotation:

> 1593 Shakes. Lucr. 468 *This moves in him more rage...To make the breach.*
>
> 1671 Milton Samson 836 *Call it furious rage To satisfie thy lust.* ns iii. 65 *The rage which possesses authors to read their writings aloud.*

Source: [What is the origin of the idiom 'all the rage'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/127804/44619)

> ***[lust](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lust)***
>   **2.**
>   a. An overwhelming desire or craving: *a lust for power*.
>   b. Intense eagerness or enthusiasm: *a lust for life*.
>   **3.** Obsolete
>   *Pleasure*; *relish*.

Source:The Free Dictionary

> **[rage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rage)**
>   1. angry fury; violent anger.
>   2. a fit of violent anger (sometimes used in combination): *a flight attendant attacked, the unfortunate victim of air rage*.
>   3. fury or violence of wind, waves, fire, disease, etc.
>   4. violence of feeling, desire, or appetite.
>   5. a violent desire or passion.
>   6. ardor; fervor; enthusiasm.
>   7. an object of current popularity; fad: *I remember when long hair was all the rage*.
>   8. Archaic. insanity.
>   *v.i*.
>   9. to act or speak with fury; show or feel violent anger.
>   10. to move, rush, dash, or surge furiously.
>   11. to proceed, continue, or prevail with great violence.